# Simple variable placeholders in Draft.js

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, draftjs

We're trying to implement variable placeholders for a feature in our app.

Essentially the user will create a template using a WYSIWYG editor and put variables into the text e.g:

```
Hello {{first_name}}
```

These variables will then be interpolated by our back end (e.g. swapping {{first_name}} with "Peter").

Our users are non-technical so we don't want them to have to add the placeholders manually. We want them to drag and drop the variables into their text from a list that we predefine.

Is there a simple way of doing this with DraftJS or CKEdior out of the box?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for A2A.

We had a similar feature requirement to add templates with placeholders for mailing.

```
Dear {{recipient.first_name}},

  Mail Body Template

With best regards,
{{sender.first_name}} {{sender.last_name}}
Manager - ABC Company.
```

Here is how we implemented it. I hope this would be helpful.

[draft-js](https://draftjs.org/) provides a [Modifier](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-modifier/) class for this very use-case.

`Modifier` API has [insertText](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-modifier/#inserttext) method to insert custom placeholder text in the content-`{{first_name}}` in your case.

```
import { EditorState, Modifier } from 'draft-js';

insertPlaceholder = placeholderText => {
  const { editorState } = this.state;

   const newContentState = Modifier.insertText(
      editorState.getCurrentContent(), // get ContentState from EditorState
      editorState.getSelection(),
      placeholderText
    );

    this.setState({
      editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(newContentState); // get EditorState with ContentState
    });
}
```

Then add a button to trigger the insertPlaceholder method.

```
<button
  onClick={() => this.insertPlaceholder('{{first_name}}')}
>
  Add First Name
</button>
```

When clicked on `Add First Name` placeholder text will be inserted at the **current `cursor` position**.

If the editor is out of focus, the text will be inserted at the **beginning**.

For Reusability, you can create a custom plugin and include it in options.
[Placeholder plugin example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PP6r.png)

**Note**:

If you have multiple placeholders, I would rather suggest using a `select input` with possible placeholder options - this will keep UI clean instead of having a bunch of buttons.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with React Hooks?

Comment: A minor refactor would do the job for hooks




    const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(defaultEditorState);

    insertPlaceholder = placeholderText => {

       const newContentState = Modifier.insertText(
          editorState.getCurrentContent(), // get ContentState from EditorState
          editorState.getSelection(),
          placeholderText
      );

       setEditorState(EditorState.createWithContent(newContentState));
    }

Comment: Awesome. Btw I got the error target range must be collapsed for `insertText`. using `replaceText` solves this

Answer (score 0):

You can create a button as follows

```
  <button
     onMouseDown={e => this.onAddText(e, '{{first_name}}' )}
  >
     ADD Name
  </button>
```

and inside onAddText function

```
import { insertText } from 'draft-js-modifiers';

onAddText = (e, text) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { editorState } = this.state;
    const EditorStat = insertText(editorState, text);
    this.setState({ editorState: EditorStat });
};
```

insertText is method provided by draft-js-modifiers

and then use this.state.editorState as follows:

```
import {
  Editor,
} from 'draft-js';

<Editor
     editorState={this.state.editorState}
/>
```